# Proving Inverse DFT

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

I have trouble understanding the proof I was provided of the IDFT, here is what I have:
$$
\nu_n = \frac{n}{\Delta N} \\
x(t) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}X(\nu)e^{i2\pi\nu_n t}d\nu \\
$$

the next step I have is the troublesome one:

$$
x(k\Delta) = \sum_{n = 0}^{N - 1} \Delta X_k e^{\frac{i2\pi n k\Delta}{\Delta N}} \frac{1}{\Delta N}
$$

It is obvious where some of the elements are canceling each other, but 
I do not understand how the $ \frac{1}{\Delta N}$ is at the end? Do we get it when we convert $d\nu$?

Thank you a lot!